# How do I improve my middleware dev skills?

Tags: wcf, web-services, workflow-foundation

I need recommendations (books/links) for improving my skills in the following-

1. Web Services ( SOAP and REST based )
2. Windows Communication Foundation (out of the box and REST based)
3. Windows Workflow Foundation

I rate myself as intermediate in web services and almost intermediate in WCF and WF. I would like to know some books/links that are meant for intermediate to advanced audience. Any other platform agnostic resources would be great too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I recommend two excellent books for learning WCF.

First, you need the WCF Bible - "[Programming WCF Services](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596521301/index.html)" by Juval Lowy.  This is THE book for WCF - Lowy covers just about everything with very thorough detail.  This is a pretty deep, technical book.  You'll want to take it slowly, at first at least.  Be sure to get the 2nd edition - it covers VS2008 SP1.

Lowy also has built an excellent library around WCF that's a companion to his book.  It's called ServiceModelEx - you can find the source for it [here](http://examples.oreilly.com/9780596521301/).  It really helps to have the book though!

Second, I suggest taking a look at "[Learning WCF](http://oreilly.com/catalog/9780596101626/index.html)" by Michele Bustamante, also by O'Reilly.  This book hasn't been updated for VS2008 and .NET 3.5 but there's still a wealth of good information here.  This book is more like a step-by-step tutorial.  It really helped me get a handle on just what WCF is and what it can do.

Beyond that the best advice has already been given. Code your butt off.  I can't stress this enough.  WCF made almost NO sense to me until I started coding.  Go through tutorials.  Pick something fun to turn into a component and see how many different ways you can access it via WCF.

Good luck and have fun!

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the usual suspects of O'Reilly and Wrox are great:

[O'Reilly](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0596521308)

[Wrox](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0470089849)

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is to keep coding also. Create clones of other's projects yourself and let that lead you.